Flutter Linking No Opening Page Using the Get Package
I want to open the same page again with different params
the issue is that if I open the post details page from any other page it works great with params. but if I open the new post from post details page but with different parameters, nothing happens only the URL updates nothing else.
Here is my code:
    SizedBox(height: 3),
    //Thread summary
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){ Get.to(ViewThread(postID: parentThreadID)); },
      child: Text(
        parentContent,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          color: Colors.grey[900],
        ),
      ),
    ),


try using Get.off instead of Get.to
 SizedBox(height: 3),
    // Thread summary
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Get.off(() => ViewThread(postID: parentThreadID));
      },
      child: Text(
        parentContent,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          color: Colors.grey[900],
        ),
      ),
    ),

